# How to use block in c

Tags: c, console-application

I have one block with integers, I need to do some task in school.

I need to group even numbers to one block (even numbers)
and i need to group odd numbers to one block (odd numbers)

I was trying to do something, but this doesn't work normally

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int tomb [] = {5, 10, 8, 3, -1, 4, 2, 9};
    int parostomb[] = {};
    int paratlantomb[] = {};
    int n = 9;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int paros = 0;
    int paratlan = 0;
    
    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
        if (tomb[i]%2 == 0) {
            parostomb[paros] = tomb[i];
            paros = paros + 1;
            printf("paros: %d\n", parostomb[paros]);
        }
        else {
            paratlantomb[paratlan] = tomb[i];
            paratlan = paratlan + 1;
            printf("Paratlan:%d\n", paratlantomb[paratlan]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please help
If you run the code you will be see the code is doesn't work normally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
int parostomb[] = {};
int paratlantomb[] = {};
```

you do not set the array size.

You need to change it to:

```
int parostomb[sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int)] = { 0 };
int paratlantomb[sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int)] = {0 };
```

So what is `sizeof (tomb)/sizeof(int)` doing? It calculates the number of elements in the array `tomb`. The first part `sizeof(tomb)` calculates the number of bytes in the array. The second part `sizeof(int)` calculates the number of bytes in an `int`. Consequently, diving the first by the second will give you the number of `int` in the array (aka the number of array elements).

`sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int)` can also be written `sizeof tomb/sizeof *tomb`. The later is typically considered the best because in case you to change the array type, e.g. use `long int` instead of `int`, you don't have to change `sizeof(int)` to `sizeof(long int)`. When using `sizeof *tomb` the actual type is handled automatically.

Further here:

```
        parostomb[paros] = tomb[i];
        paros = paros + 1;
        printf("paros: %d\n", parostomb[paros]);
```

You increment `paros` before printing so you do **not** print the newly assigned value.

Change to:

```
        parostomb[paros] = tomb[i];
        printf("paros: %d\n", parostomb[paros]);
        paros = paros + 1;
```

Further here:

```
int tomb [] = {5, 10, 8, 3, -1, 4, 2, 9};
...
int n = 9;  <-------------------- The array size is only 8
```

To avoid such bugs do:

```
int tomb [] = {5, 10, 8, 3, -1, 4, 2, 9};
...
int n = sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int);
```

Putting it all together, your code should be:

```
int main(void)
{
    int tomb [] = {5, 10, 8, 3, -1, 4, 2, 9};
    int parostomb[sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int)] = {0};
    int paratlantomb[sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int)] = {0};
    int n = sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int);
    int i = 0;
    int paros = 0;
    int paratlan = 0;
    
    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
        if (tomb[i]%2 == 0) {
            parostomb[paros] = tomb[i];
            printf("paros: %d\n", parostomb[paros]);
            paros = paros + 1;
        }
        else {
            paratlantomb[paratlan] = tomb[i];
            printf("Paratlan:%d\n", paratlantomb[paratlan]);
            paratlan = paratlan + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Paratlan:5
paros: 10
paros: 8
Paratlan:3
Paratlan:-1
paros: 4
paros: 2
Paratlan:9
```

**That said...** It seems strange that you save the numbers into two arrays that you never really use. It would make more sense to generate the arrays first and then print them in separate loops. Like:

```
int main(void)
{
    int tomb [] = {5, 10, 8, 3, -1, 4, 2, 9};
    int parostomb[sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int)] = {0};
    int paratlantomb[sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int)] = {0};
    int n = sizeof(tomb)/sizeof(int);
    int i = 0;
    int paros = 0;
    int paratlan = 0;
    
    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
        if (tomb[i]%2 == 0) {
            parostomb[paros] = tomb[i];
            paros = paros + 1;
        }
        else {
            paratlantomb[paratlan] = tomb[i];
            paratlan = paratlan + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Even numbers: ");
    for (i=0; i < paros; i++){
        printf("%d ", parostomb[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Odd numbers: ");
    for (i=0; i < paratlan; i++){
        printf("%d ", paratlantomb[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
Even numbers: 10 8 4 2 
Odd numbers: 5 3 -1 9
```

Comment: it divides the array size by the size of one array element so you get the number of elements. Btw. I yould suggest to use `sizeof tomb / sizeof *tomb` instead of `... / sizeof(int)`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Fully agree. `sizeof(int)` is just easier to grasp for new programmers. Anyway, the answer is updated to include that part.